# How can I use an event object as a condition in an if statement in Java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to Java and I am making an app where I need to have multiple containers do the same kind of thing. What I plan to do is use the event objects to find out which one was selected and then call the same function. I don't have any code at the moment.
How would I use the event object to do so? Or is there a better way?
Another way of putting it would be like when a person touches one, for example, imageView the if with the relevant event object as its condition will return true and activate the code in that if statement. A similar thing would happen if another imageView is touched

Comment: I recommend looking into [ImageButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton). It has a `setOnClickListener` method.

Comment: thanks for the recommendation :)